# Can the two columns and little triangle thing be removed?

Tags: columns

Can the two columns and triangle thing be taken off so I  can add a porch.Is it a major job?

[image]

Comment: this is indeed a major job, not  a do-it-yourself thing.

Answer (score 1):

That triangle marquee is called a gable. And the house is built in Colonial style.
And of course it can be removed, provided you get the required permit.

One alternative that may be less costly and is in line with this style, and may be even a bit more classical, is to keep the columns and gable roof but add a balcony on the first level to do the job of both a porch and create an open air entertainment space. here is roughly an example. again you can build it even bigger than this so that your columns penetrate through the balcony.

[image: circular portico.]